# The development server has disconnected. Refresh the page if necessary

Tags: reactjs, webpack, development-environment, ws

1. The application is in a development environment
2. "react-scripts": "4.0.3"

When I lift the application with docker it works fine, but when connecting with the mosquitto broker I get this error in the console:

```
The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

After that error appears, the application does not refresh

- The application only works well if I initialize it before the broker, if I start the broker before the application does not run and remains as in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes. this is the default behaviour of Webpack dev server. since it cannot connect (websocket) to server, it prints this. You need to re-establish the connection by refreshing the window

Comment: @Prakash S That is the problem it does not let me update the window. When I try to update it hangs around for a while and then does nothing and is displayed 'Cannot access this website' in the browser.

Comment: Cannot access this website means the server is down. did you check your terminal for logs?

Comment: @Prakash S Nothing new appears in terminal and in browser console I get this warning: VM48: 7148 crbug / 1173575, non-JS module files are out of date.

Comment: you can create a code sandbox with your code and we can investigate